# Can you suggest best practice for p2p socket programming?

Tags: c++, performance, sockets

I'm writing a P2P program in C++ such that the program is running in multiple hosts and each host is connected directly to each other (i.e. full graph).

My question is about the consideration that I should take into account when dealing with sockets in that case.

I need the communication to not a bottleneck and have really good time performance. Should I use separate thread for each connection? or some kind of infinite loop? what about accepting new connections? (i.e. `accept()`). Doit make any difference whether it is under linux or Windows? What other matters should I consider?

I found several question deal with a subset of my problem, but they weren't fully addressed my concerns. ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687215/most-efficient-way-to-handle-a-client-connection-socket-programming) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095567/socket-programming-best-practices) for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asynchronous networking for such things, [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and [`QtNetwork`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html) being good examples. They use system-dependent features (like [`epoll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), [`iocp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx), [`kqueue`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) and others) that take 0% CPU (while an infinite loop would normally take 100%). The performance is great, provided that the library is used properly.

I advise reading a bit about something like `epoll` to understand how it works under the hood.

By the way, this approach can use any number of threads (even be single-threaded), so you can configure it for improving performance.